# Range based for-loop with &

Tags: c++, c++11

I haven't found a question that answers the part I'm confused on, and I apologize if someone did answer it.

I'm confused on whats going on in this for-loop, how is it looping through the addresses?

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for(const int &arrEntry : arr) {
     cout << arrEntry << " ";
}
```

Comment: "Addresses"? What exactly are you talking about? Where do "addresses" come into the picture and why are you mentioning them?

Comment: That `&` makes  `arrEntry` a reference to an element in `arr`. What this really means to you is best looked up in your preferred C++ language reference or textbook.

Comment: How the range-based `for` works is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about, but if you're interested, here's a pretty good documentation page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for Note: You need to have a pretty good handle on basic iterators to have a hope of understanding most of it.

Comment: Alright my confusion starts at the "&". If it wasn't there, the way the loop would work is arrEntry would be assigned to 1, and then 2, and then 3,... and it would print each out.

Comment: An example of where the `&` becomes useful: `for(int arrEntry : arr){ arrEntry++; }` would have no discernible after effects. `arrEntry` is just another local variable with a copy of a value in the array. A decent compiler would discard the loop as pointless. But with `for(int & arrEntry : arr){ arrEntry++; }` `arrEntry` IS an entry in the array and the `++` affects the value in the array. `for(const int &arrEntry : arr)` may have some performance advantages over `for(int arrEntry : arr)`, no copy  is made, but a decent compiler would figure that out on its own and eliminate the copy anyway.

Comment: have you ran the code? Did you see with `&` is still prints `1 2 3 4 5`. So clearly no addresses come into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the placement of `&` is causing confusion. Remember that C++ doesn't care where you put spaces. Since this: `for (const int &arrEntry : arr)` is a *declaration* of a new variable `arrEntry` for use inside the loop, the use of `&` on the left-hand side of its name means we are defining an object that has a *reference* type, specifically `arrEntry` is a *reference to a `const int`*. This means that within the loop, `arrEntry` is not a copy of the data you're looping over, only a reference to it. The `const` means that you can't change its value.

If this were not a declaration, and if `arrEntry` were defined previously, then the expression `&arrEntry` would indeed be taking the address of `arrEntry`. Within the body of the loop, `arrEntry` is already defined, and so you can take its address with `&arrEntry`

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
for(const int &arrEntry : arr){
     cout << arrEntry << " "; // prints a const int
     cout << &arrEntry << " "; // prints a pointer to a const int
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm starting to get this!

Comment: Note to those coming in from C# and similar languages: Reference type as used in this  answer does not mean what you are used to. Make sure you understand the second half of the sentence before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

The range-based for loop in C++ is actually just syntactic sugar that is equivalent to the following (provided by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement;

// is equivalent to:

{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement

    }
}
```

In the above code block, `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are equivalent to `std::begin(__range)` and `std::end(__range)` respectively.

So in the case of using `const int &arrEntry`, `arrEntry` is actually declared inside the "real" (normal) for loop and thus in each iteration it refers to a different object in the range, as if by using the raw iterators directly.

Note that this would not be possible if `arrEntry` was declared outside the normal for loop, as references cannot be repointed to refer to a different object.

Another important (side) fact to consider is that `range_expression` is kept alive for the entire duration of the loop, which means you can use a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) there (e.g. calling a function that returns a `std::vector<int>` by value.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the &arrEntry is a reference to arr. This is implicit in the Ranged based For-Loop.

```
for(const int &arrEntry : arr){
     cout << arrEntry << " ";
}
```

You could do it without the reference, the result is the same. 
But notice the value of arr is copied to arrEntry.

```
for(const int arrEntry : arr){
     cout << arrEntry << " ";
}
```

Comment: if `arrEntry` were a reference to `arr`, then its type would actually have to be `int(&)[5]`. You could reword your answer to be clearer about what `arrEntry` is

Comment: `arrEntry` is reference to `arr` entry not to entire `arr`.  And result might be the same but some cases performance is better when used references.